# AndroidRTC fatal error when closing application

Tags: android, webrtc, rtc

> I'm using androidRTC, https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC
>
> The application crashing when closing. This error appears in the log:

```
# Fatal error in ../../talk/app/webrtc/java/jni/peerconnection_jni.cc, line 926
    # Check failed: 0 == (reinterpret_cast<MediaSourceInterface*>(j_p))->Release() (0 vs. 1)
    # Unexpected refcount.
```

Comment: the same problem happen when change the orientation from portrait to landscape